# Impact of migrating app from GAE M/S datastore to HRD

Tags: google-app-engine

When migrating the app from M/S datastore to HRD there are certain pitfalls to avoid. I had a question on one such specific area where it says "Entity ids of the same Kind are not always unique".

To explain it further here's an example.

1. Lets say I have 3 entities Customer, Contact, Address as below
2. Contact entity references Customer using customer key as
   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key
3. Address entity references Customer using customer key as Long

The 3 classes are:

```
public class Customer {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key id;

  @Persistent
  private String name;
}

public class Contact {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key id;

  @Persistent
  private String name;

  @Persistent
  private Key customerId;
}


public class Address {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key id;

  @Persistent
  private String address;

  @Persistent
  private Long customerId;
}
```

All the entities are root entities.

Now when we migrate what will happen to **customerId** in Contact and Address entities? Will they still work or do we need to do anything special with them before migration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is to do with how keys are built. An entity's key will be made up from:

- Your application id
- The current namespace
- The hierarchy  of parent(s)   `<-- this allows ids to be non-unique within a kind`
- The Kind name
- The given `key_name` OR `id`

So for a key to be unique, any one of those parts could change. Within a single kind, within a single namespace within your app, the only time ids may not be unique is when you have set a `parent`for that entity.

This means all your root entities as defined, **will have unique ids/names**.

If you need to guarantee that assigned ids are unique within a kind even across entities with an ancestor hierarchy, you could;

1. Re-think your design. If you are referring to entities by id accross entity groups without needing/having the parent, you might have applied entity groups somewhere they were not needed
2. You could [allocateIds](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.html) manually based on the root version of the Kind

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Since all our entities are root entities, we can continue to use pm.newQuery(<classname>, "where customerId = <id as long value>") with HRD without worrying about duplicate keys. The flip side to it would be eventual consistency. Does it take between 2 - 5 seconds for data to appear across entire HRD?

Comment: Fetching entities by id (therefore key) directly is always strongly consistant, eventual consistency will only show it's face when doing queries over multiple entity groups.